# Can I use a VPN (I use VPN) for one Firefox profile on Windows?

Tags: firefox, vpn, tunnel, split-tunnel

Some services do not accept connections from VPNs. I would like to route the traffic that can use a VPN through one Firefox profile, and the rest through another. Is this possible?

Nordvpn supports "split tunneling" which is close. https://www.reddit.com/r/nordvpn/comments/m5hoka/only_use_some_apps_over_nordvpn/ , however there doesn't seem to be a way of matching only one instance of Firefox.

As a workaround I am going to use Brave for some traffic and Firefox for other traffic. But this not optimal.

I wonder if I could use an HTTP proxy somehow.

Comment: Use [Mozilla VPN](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/fi/kb/what-mozilla-vpn-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @harrymc that looks like it would work... but I have already paid for nordvpn ahead of time, and mozilla vpn would be another 5 bucks a month. But... you suggestion made me wonder if there was an equivalent plugin for nordvpn and there is! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nordvpn-proxy-extension/